# Which $\pm1$ matrices are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find which matrices $M$ with $M_{i,j} \in \{-1,1\}$ have all their rows orthogonal?   Do they exist and if so, what form and dimensions do they take?

I can find 2 by 2 matrices such as

\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1\\
  -1 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}

Also 4 by 4 matrices such as

\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
  -1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
  -1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
   1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}

but I can't find any 6 by 6 ones and I am not at all sure about non-square matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [Hadamard Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix). A matrix can have $\pm 1$ entries and be orthogonal only if it is dimension $1,2,$ or $4k$ for $ k =1,2,3,4\ldots$.

Look up the Hadamard Conjecture to learn more about these.
As pointed out by Will Jagy, existence is an open question.

I should add, since $6$ is not a multiple of $4$, then no such $6 \times 6$ matrix exists.

Comment: "The most important open question in the theory of Hadamard matrices is that of existence. The Hadamard conjecture proposes that a Hadamard matrix of order 4k exists for every positive integer k."......"As of 2008, there are 13 multiples of 4 less than or equal to 2000 for which no Hadamard matrix of that order is known.[8] They are: 668, 716, 892, 1004, 1132, 1244, 1388, 1436, 1676, 1772, 1916, 1948, and 1964."

Comment: Thanks very much. How about non-square matrices of this form with fewer rows than columns?

Comment: Just a sort of unconfirmed guess, but I think if we have fewer rows than columns we would need to have the number of rows be 1,2 or 4k. Just a conjecture that I have not tested.

Comment: You cannot have three mutually orthogonal vectors with elements $\pm1$ unless the dimension is a multiple of $4.$  This means that the number of columns in a $\pm1$ matrix with at least three mutually orthogonal rows is a multiple of $4.$  If there is an $n\times n$ Hadamard matrix, then there is an $m\times n$ matrix with mutually orthogonal rows for any $m\le n.$  Should the Hadamard matrix conjecture fail for some $n,$ it may still be possible to construct an $m\times n$ matrix with mutually orthogonal rows for fairly large $m.$  You might try a search on "partial Hadamard matrices".